# How to run MbUnit tests in VS2013

Tags: mbunit, visual-studio-2013

I installed Gallio&MbUnit 3.4.14, via NuGet. Also I installed Gallio Bundle with Icarus runner from https://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/

VS does not see the MbUnit tests I wrote. Though I can run the MbUnit tests via Icarus Runner.

1. Is Gallio and/or MbUnit compatible with VS2013 Ultimate?
2. Is there a way to make VS2013 see MbUnit tests?

Thanks.

Comment: http://testdriven.net/